# trouble with fixing elements in row in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface

look at the pic

[image]

I don't want  elements to change their positions especially in horizontal axis when their strings changed
I mean it should be like a table with  fixed columns.
can I do this just with row?

Comment: Can you include  [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because you set a defined width for spacing.
You could use a combination of `Flexible` & `Expanded` widgets to wrap all the children in your `Row`.
That should align them correctly.

[image: Result]

You can find the corresponding code [here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=756da2919ab1f7eba2de516191973b64)